# My child Activity does not send result back to parent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am attempting to create a ToDo list for a class that I am in, and how I have the app is that I have an EditText on top to enter an item in the TDL. and then I am using an extended tablelayout to display the items. I also have a button that calls to a second activity that then has 2 other buttons to get the time and date to (hopefully) display on the TDL item after I hit the Done button on the button (where I would like to go back to the main activity) So far I am testing this on an AVD.

So what I think my issue is that I dont think my second activity is passing back the info that I want. According to the debugger, the onActivityResults method from the first one gets called earlier than the second activity gets called.

Here is the first Activity:

```
package com.parrishb.todo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ToDoActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences pref; 

    public final static int ACTIVITY =1;

    public static Globals g;

    public ToDoView tdv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);

        final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

        Button mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
        tdv = (ToDoView)findViewById(R.id.tdv);


        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
                        tdv.addRow(ToDoActivity.this, myEditText.getText().toString());

                        myEditText.setText("");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        // CLick listener for the date/time button
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(ToDoActivity.this, DatePickerActivity.class), ACTIVITY);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode== RESULT_OK && requestCode== ACTIVITY){
            String append= (new StringBuilder().append(data.getStringExtra("Time"))
                    .append(" ").append(data.getStringExtra("Date")).toString());
            tdv.editRow(ToDoActivity.this, append);
        }

    }




}
```

Here is my second activity:

```
package com.parrishb.todo;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
public class DatePickerActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
    private TextView mTimeDisplay;
    private Button mPickTime;

    private Button done;

    private int mhour;
    private int mminute;

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buttonclick);

        mDateDisplay =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
        mPickDate =(Button)findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
        mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
        done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.done);


        //Pick time's click event listener
        mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);


            }

        });

        //PickDate's click event listener 
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);


            }
        });

        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //DatePickerActivity.this.finishActivityFromChild(DatePickerActivity.this, ToDoActivity.ACTIVITY);
                //finishActivity(ToDoActivity.ACTIVITY);
                //return;
                //DatePickerActivity.this.finish(ToDoActivity.ACTIVITY);
                //finish();
                DatePickerActivity.this.finish();

            }
        });

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);




    }


    @Override
    public void finish(){
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("Date", mDateDisplay.getText().toString());
            b.putString("Time", mTimeDisplay.getText().toString());
        resultIntent.putExtras(b);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        super.finish();
    }

    //-------------------------------------------update date----------------------------------------//    
    private void updateDate() {

        mDateDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                .append(mDay).append("/")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));

    }

    //-------------------------------------------update time----------------------------------------//    
    public void updatetime()
    {
        mTimeDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                .append(pad(mhour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(mminute))); 

    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }




    //Datepicker dialog generation  

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDate();
        }
    };


    // Timepicker dialog generation
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mhour = hourOfDay;
            mminute = minute;
            updatetime();
        }


    };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeSetListener, mhour, mminute, true);

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had scratched the second activity and brought the date and time picker into the main activity.